# How to achieve a "vapor" text look

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, typefaces

So, I see these two posters on Pinterest and I was really wondering about how such vaporous, grainy looks were achieved. I thought maybe scanning then working on the scan in Photoshop ? I have no idea. If anyone could help me do the same aesthetic, it would be lovely.

Thank you really much!

[image]

Comment: Why would you _want_ to? It looks terrible and it’s virtually illegible (“je ne vois pas [bleh??] ce que tu veux dire”?). **Edit:** Ah, _bien_, of course. Still. Bloody hard to read.

Comment: Perhaps the Liquify filter, plus a bit of smudging/blurring.

Comment: .... displacement map ....

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think this is the ironic point of this piece and you stepped into it with both feet and your eyes open ^^'

Comment: @Vincent I wouldn’t say there’s anything ironic about it. It illustrates its point very well, but it still looks horrible, and it’s _too_ illegible (to me, anyway). There are less terrible-looking and less illegible ways to illustrate the point in the same manner.

Comment: Oh wow! @Scott thanks for this comment. I just learned a new skill :D I would always write text on uneven surfaces (like a cloth) manually, by using distory/liquify tools. Never knew about displacement map.

Comment: er... some of us have *no idea* what it's supposed to say `:)` you multi-lingual users.. you.... i don't know what you mean `:D`

Comment: @Scott “Je ne vois pas bien ce que tu veux dire” = “I can’t really tell what you’re trying to say”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was somewhat kidding.. Google translated the phrase to "I don't know what you mean" -- as in my comment above `:D` (for the record.. I did know "je ne voix pas ", but had no idea for the rest.  `:)` )

Answer (score 1):

Due to the subtle blurs and fading opacity it is **highly** doubtful this was created in Illustrator. 
It's most likely a Photoshop project. I only mention this due to the question tags. Trying to pull off such an image in Illustrator would be a lesson in frustration more than anything. It *could possibly* be done via gradient meshes, opacity masks, etc.. but I'd not want to tackle that project unless I was being paid *very well* for it.

---

Text can be easily distorted by using the **Displacement Map** feature within Photoshop.

Displacement maps distort one layer based upon a greyscale "map". The map is essentially a greyscale image which is used as a sort of topography for distortion, white areas are seen as "high" and black areas are seen as "low". Grey area are transition regions between the two.

Essentially, you'd set the text up straight, create a greyscale image for the map, then use `Filter > Distort > Displace` to distort the text with the map...

[image]

It can take **considerable** effort to create a displacement map which distorts in a manner you want.

In the *particular sample* in the question, chances are high that there was some *additional processing* after using the Displace filter, such as reducing opacity, blurring, and other filters used such as the Maximum/Minimum filters.

There are *hundreds* of online tutorials if you merely search for "Photoshop Displacement Map". Here are just a few top hits...

- https://photoshopcafe.com/tutorials/dispmap/dispmap.htm
- https://www.colesclassroom.com/using-the-displacement-map-in-photoshop/
- https://expertphotography.com/displacement-map-photoshop/
- https://designpanoply.com/blog/how-to-conform-text-to-a-surface-using-a-displacement-map-in-photoshop

<sup>I have no affiliation with any of the links. They are merely added here for ease.</sup>